# Cytoscape v3.8.2 problems on mac OS 11.5.2 - system check failure

Tags: cytoscape

I recently tried downloading Cytoscape v3.8.2 to my computer (mac OS 11.5.2). I saw the warning about the issue with the latest mac OS update and downloaded the `disable-opencl.dummy` file and placed it in the `CytoscapeConfiguration` directory as suggested. I still had trouble opening Cytoscape so I continued looking through the suggested troubleshooting protocol. I checked my Java version and ran the system checker script:

```
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
############# Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Mac ##############
Target Cytoscape version: 3.8.2
Your shell is bash
Fail: This version of OS is not supported: 11.5.2
Please upgrade your system to 10.11 or newer.
```

I wasn't sure how to proceed with an error that says my systems needs to be upgraded to 10.11 or newer when I'm already running 11.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape requires java 11 and will not work with Java 12, unfortunately.  Typically we support only the LTS versions, so we plan on supporting Java 17 (the next LTS version) with Cytoscape 3.10.  Try installing Java 11 and see if things work better for you.

-- scooter

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I installed Java 11.0.12 on my device (made version 11 my default) and was still not able to run Cytoscape 3.8.2 (which was the version. So I downloaded Cytoscape 3.7.2 and was able to run that. For what I currently need it for, this will do. Not planning to mess with updates again in the near future.